# Is this sentence corret? Although she was tired, she went to the gym, and she worked out for an hour

Tags: grammar

Although she was tired, she went to the gym, and she worked out for an hour.

Could you kindly help me analyze the structure of the sentence?

I am kind of certain "Although she was tired" is a dependent clause. But what about "she went to the gym" and "and she worked out for an hour"? Are they independent clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. There are two independent clauses.  They are linked by the conjunction "and".